# MVC Area Routing not working for one specific area in my web application....Returning 500.19 with wrong phsyical path

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, iis

I have an asp.net mvc web application with multiple areas.

There are about 15 areas within this application all of these route correctly except for one area.

This area blows up when I go directly to the index page with a 500.19 error.

The routing, controller, and views are essentially very similar for all areas involved.

The one thing that I have noticed is that the error provided shows the incorrect area path (physical path) for the specific view that is being requested.  This can be seen in the image provided, but it is showing this as the physical path to the robin index view. :

C:\Projects\mvc\Test\BatmanProject\Index

Whereas it should be showing something like this. :

C:\Projects\mvc\Test\BatmanProject\Areas\Robin\Views\Home\Index

As you can see below it is attempting to find the index view directly in the batmanproject versus looking in the robin area.  Whereas all the other areas (Riddler, Joker, etc etc) are finding the index directly in their corresponding area without throwing a 500.19 error.

[image]

I know it is not web.config related because all the other areas are working.  I have tried numerous things such as. :

- wiping out the host config and temp aspnet files
- clearing out all the applications in my iis
- running aspnet_regiis -r
- numerous other fixes

I am just confused as to why it would occur for this specific area and not the others any one else seen an error like this?

***Route having issue

```
http://localhost/BatmanProject/Robin/Home/Index
```

***AreaRegistration

```
public override string AreaName
        {
            get
            {
                return "Robin";
            }
        }

        public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
        {
            context.MapRoute(
                "Robin_default",
                "Robin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
```

Comment: Can you post the route that's having an issue?

Comment: @mmillican it is posted above